# Light switch has 3 sets of wires i matched all the colors light is on but breaker trips when i turn it off

Tags: wiring

Light switch has 3 diffrent sets of wireers ive matched all the colors light will came on instantly but tripd breaker when i cut it off

Comment: can you add snap of it?

Comment: Can you edit your question so it actually a question with proper grammar and punctuation?

Comment: VTC - This question cannot be answered with the terse information provided. All that can be said is that it is wired up wrong. If this can be cleaned up and more information added (including possibly some clear photos) the close vote can be removed.

Comment: Is this a single switch (so called 1-pole switch) or is this one of a pair of two switches (so called 3-way) which control lights? How many screw contacts are on the switch--two or three? (Excluding a ground.)

Comment: It sounds like you have made a wiring mistake in which the light is always on , and when the switch is flipped it makes a dead short which trips the breaker by over current. Matching colors of wires is not a rule for wiring a switch.  We need more information.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just connect all the wires of the same color. This is not a rule for wiring either a single switch or pair of switches that controls a light.

One possibility is that your switch box has 3 cables coming into it as follows below. This assumes that this is a single pole switch, that is, this is the only switch controlling the light in question, that is, the switch has only two screw contacts (excluding the ground contact if any) not three contacts.

(1) cable (two wires + gnd, usu B, W and bare ground) for line power in, i.e., from the panel and the black in this cable always hot if the breaker is on,

(2) cable for "feed" to other boxes (two wires usu B and W + gnd) The black will not be hot if disconnected in the switch box,

(3) cable connecting switch to light fixture (usu B, W, and bare gnd). This is called a switch loop. When disconnected the B is not hot.

Does this correspond to what you have in the box?

Answer (score 1):

*Colors* are only there to help you identify **function**.  You still need to know what you are doing.

You don't, and as such, you should not be playing with mains electricity until you do.

Hit a library or a big-box home improvement store and look at all the books on house wiring.  Find one that seems easy for you to access and understand.  Then read it (almost) cover to cover.  There will be chapters you just won't use, like how to wire a hot tub, or subpanel in an outbuilding, you can skip those (but it will help your understanding if you don't).

Once  you've done that, it helps to browse a forum like this one on a regular basis, as we often deal with oddball situations that aren't in the book.  And if you have general questions, search or ask.

Don't just Google the information you think you need. **You don't know what information you need** until you have a well-rounded understanding.

*And by the way, there is no color standard in the USA, and this is deliberate.  The doctrine in the USA (and many other nations) is that electricians should actually measure and think, not assume based on wire color.  Needless to say, you won't be going anywhere without skill.*